# How to access the data from database into groovy using filters

Tags: groovy

Here I try to get the data from uploadcdr table but I cannot understand how the filters work. Please explain me.

```
def private getFilteredUploadCDR(filters, GrailsParameterMap params) {

    params.max = params?.max?.toInteger() ?: pagination.max
    params.offset = params?.offset?.toInteger() ?: pagination.offset
    params.sort = params?.sort ?: pagination.sort
    params.order = params?.order ?: pagination.order

   return UploadCDRFileDTO.createCriteria().list(
            max:    params.max,
            offset: params.offset
    ) {

        and {
            filters.each { filter ->
                   log.debug("fileter  field ${filter.field}")
                if (filter.value) {

                         addToCriteria(filter.getRestrictions());
                   }
             }

         }

        // apply sorting
       SortableCriteria.sort(params, delegate)
    }
}
```

Comment: Summary and description does not seem to match.

Comment: in the above code how the filters works

Comment: Add grails tag, please.

Comment: what is grails tag i cannot understand